# jsonp and REST GET call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jsonp

I have two projects, an older one, which works, and a newer one. Both projects have to make a cross-domain call.

On the older project, I use jsonp to talk to the server and get a response, such as:

```
var myUrl = "http://www.myserver.whatever/somepage.php";
jsonp(myUrl, "ajaxResponse");

function ajaxResponse(data) { alert(data.response); }
```

In my new totally unrelated project, I have to talk to a service. The web page is a local file on the client talking to a CentOS daemon written by a software vendor. I can communicate to the daemon through REST GET calls. An example of a call would be, which works, as I entered the following in a Mozilla Firefox browser window:

localhost:8080/mfds/info

I thought that the easiest way to communicate to the daemon would be through jsonp, like I did previously, so:

```
var myUrl = "http://localhost:8080/mfds/info";
jsonp(myUrl, "ajaxResponse2");

function ajaxResponse2(data) { alert(data.response); }
```

Sadly, I never get to the ajaxResponse2() function. What am I doing wrong? Is jsonp() not a REST GET call? How do I fix the code?

I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsonpCrossDomain.js"></script>
```

to load the jsonp script. As mentioned earlier, if I use the URL associated with my old project, the code works, just not with localhost:8080:/mfds/info, which works nicely in a browser. The daemon service returns html code.

UPDATE:
Based on the comment below, I did not realize that jsonp has to be on both sides. I originally tried the following code, but this code threw a cross domain error (or so I think, actual error below), which led me to try the JSONP call, but I cannot use that either.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:8080/mfds/info',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    error: function (error)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    complete: function (data_response)
    {

        alert(data_response.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Error message from the $.ajax call:

{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"[Exception... \"\" nsresult: \"0x805e0006 ()\" location:\"js frame ::file:///home/user/Documents/myproejct/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js ::  :: line 6\" data: no]"}

Comment: jsonp is essentially just a javascript file request. a valid jsonp response is javascript that executes a specific function with a parameter that contains the data you want. If the service doesn't return valid jsonp, then you can't use jsonp.

Comment: The remote service has to support jsonp. It looks like this one doesn't. Your best bet is probably a server-side proxy.

Comment: You are right. There is no support for jsonp on the daemon side. I did not realize that support had to be on both sides. I was specifically told "REST GET" only. There is still the cross domain issue. I am not sure what you mean by "service-side proxy".

Comment: Create an ajax call that calls a service on your server, and that service calls the remote service, passing the response back. It works because server-side cross-domain calls are not restricted by the same origin policy.

Comment: That seems overtly complicated to implement; creating daemons and interacting with it, and everything else. I just want to make a cross domain (cross port really) call from JavaScript.

Comment: Your options are jsonp (which won't work), CORS (which I don't think will work, you'd need to be able to modify the response headers of the "remote" site), or a server-side proxy. The server-side proxy doesn't have to be complex, just a php script would work fine.

Comment: What would the PHP have to do? I can write a PHP file and even parse the JSONP call, as I already have a PHP file from the other project. I know how to pass data too. I just need what you have in mind inside the PHP file after I extract the data, which I presume is the URL.

Comment: Oh, I think that I understand. In PHP I load the contents of the URL to a string, and then pass that back. Got it!

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: Jason, I just realized that I cannot use my web hosting company as the recipient of the PHP file, because the PHP server there would have no knowledge of "localhost:8080" on the client machine, which is inside a firewall. I would have to install a web hosting platform with PHP on each client that the machine is on. That is a lot of extra software. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I didn't realize this would live on client machines. If you don't want to install a web server with your solution, this may not work for you. A simple WinForms app may be far easier.

Comment: CentOS does have PHP and apache installed. I got that working yesterday. Interfacing to PHP to retrieve a content was cool, but looks like simple Ajax might work for me too. I did not post an update yesterday, because the driver kept returning blank text, which the author of the driver feels might be his problem (not specifying the content type). More soon.